# WordPress not able to connect to Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: php, wordpress, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to deploy WordPress to `Heroku`. I have PostgreSQL add-on.

Here is my `DATABASE_URL` config variable.

```
DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://tsgmwcymsebolk:K5ateJnlrzpJXqy82ozMu9tk1n@ec2-184-72-240-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1rssf7lqrt6gt'
```

And here is my `wp-config.php`

```
<?php
$db = parse_url($_ENV["DATABASE_URL"]);
define('DB_NAME', trim($db["path"],"/"));
define('DB_USER', $db["user"]);
define('DB_PASSWORD', $db["pass"]);
define('DB_HOST', $db["host"]);
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

define('AUTH_KEY',         getenv('AUTH_KEY'));
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  getenv('SECURE_AUTH_KEY'));
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    getenv('LOGGED_IN_KEY'));
define('NONCE_KEY',        getenv('NONCE_KEY'));
define('AUTH_SALT',        getenv('AUTH_SALT'));
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', getenv('SECURE_AUTH_SALT'));
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   getenv('LOGGED_IN_SALT'));
define('NONCE_SALT',       getenv('NONCE_SALT'));

$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

When i open my application.It says `Error establishing a database connection`

Any idea what is going on ?